# Using MQTT (AWS MQ) via Squid Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, proxy, activemq-classic, squid

I got several devices coming from an IPSec Tunnel into a public subnet. 
Now I set up a squid proxy to allow the devices to access http/https resources.

Another part of the devices is a [MQTT Client](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang) that should connect to the MQ Server at AWS.

The MQ Server is in the same subnet and is generally publicly available. 
From an EC2 instance inside the subnet and from the public internet, I am able to ping the MQ server.

It seems that the address resolution is working. Nevertheless, the connection is refused.

`Network Error: dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:8883: i/o timeout`

I tried it with and without setting the proxy in the programm:

```
os.Setenv("http_proxy", "http://10.0.1.XXX:3129"),
os.Setenv("https_proxy", "http://10.0.1.XXX:3129"),
```

The permissions are set to allow traffic from all sources to port 8883.

The first question is if MQTT is able to communicate over a squid proxy.

Next question would be if I misconfigured something in the proxy.

```
# Ports
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl SSL-ports port 8883

acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 8883

acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl SSL method CONNECT

acl all src all
http_access allow all

http_port 10.0.1.XXX:3129
```

If MQTT isn't abe to communicate via SSL is there a supported protocoll that may be used? OpenWire, AMQP, STOMP, WSS

Are there alternative ways for the device to get their way to the public internet?

Comment: AMQ usually connects via TCP or similar (OpenWire etc) so squid wouldn't care about those. Have you checked your AWS security/firewall settings as they usually block most things unless enabled specifically.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I finally came up with a socks5 proxy. This works fine.